# Displaying tree on JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, recursion, tree

I need to display tree on JSP page. How can I do that? I have following object:

```
public class Node {
    private Long id;
    private Long parentId;
    private String name;
    private List<Node> children;

    // Getters & setters

}
```

Answer (score 17):

Roll your own with jsp recursion

In `Controller.java`

```
Node root = getTreeRootNode();
request.setAttribute("node", root);
```

In `main.jsp` page

```
<jsp:include page="node.jsp"/>
```

In `node.jsp`

```
<c:forEach var="node" items="${node.children}">
    <!-- TODO: print the node here -->
    <c:set var="node" value="${node}" scope="request"/>
    <jsp:include page="node.jsp"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Based on http://web.archive.org/web/20130509135219/http://blog.boyandi.net/2007/11/21/jsp-recursion/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try http://www.soft82.com/download/windows/tree4jsp/

It is also downloadable from http://www.einnovates.com/jsptools/tree4jsp/tree4jsp_v1.2.zip

Answer (score 0):

[Jsp tree Project](http://jsptree.sourceforge.net/) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use one of the available tag libraries. 
For example:

http://beehive.apache.org/docs/1.0/netui/tagsTree.html

The following discussion can help  too.
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=46659

Answer (score 0):

Just check this JSP tree. It is simple and has minimum Java Scripts. I used velocity templates and JSP Tag class.

[simple JSP tree](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsptree-simple/)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Compilation from the other answers. *Tested.*</sub>

---

#### Recursion on JSP tags

Unit.java

```java
public class Unit {
    private String name;
    private HashSet<Unit> units;

    // getters && setters
}
```

Employees.java

```java
public class Employees {
    private HashSet<Unit> units;

    // getters && setters
}
```

Application.java

```java
...
request.setAttribute("employees", employees);
request.getRequestDispatcher("EmployeeList.jsp").forward(request, response);
...
```

EmployeeList.jsp

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="unit" items="${employees.getUnits()}">
                <li>
                    <c:set var="unit" value="${unit}" scope="request"/>
                    <jsp:include page="Unit.jsp"/>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </body>
<html>
```

Unit.jsp

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<span>${unit.getName()}</span>
...
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="innerUnit" items="${unit.getUnits()}">
        <li>
            <c:set var="unit" value="${innerUnit}" scope="request"/>
            <jsp:include page="Unit.jsp"/>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```