# Display tree structure on a jsp using Recursion and JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I would like to implement a tree structure in my JSP baised web-application using recursion and JSTL.The values of tree is populated from database using java(using some list or map..).I know this question  may be asked by some peoples.but i didn't get any idea from those resources.Please help me..

Here is my Table Structure for company table.

```
      Column                Type

      Company_id            int

      Company_parent_id     int 

      Company_name         varchar(50)
```

Class Company

```
     public Class Company{
            private int companyId;
            private int companyParantId;
            private String companyName;

     //getters&setters
     }
```

Sample tree structure that i watnt to implement.

```
    1
      1.1
      1.2
          1.2.1
                1.2.1.1

   2
      2.1
   3
      3.1
          3.1.1
      .....
   n 
      n.1
     ....
```

My question is How can i implement Recursion in jsp with the help of JSTL?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [Displaying tree on JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638653/displaying-tree-on-jsp-page) post.

There is good discussion about how to achieve it manually (using jsp recursion) and also a good list of third-party utilities that can easily do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented a very similar structure.  Simply by building the list and recording the parent id, it is possible using Jquery and the jquery.treeTable.js plugin to display this hierarchy as a tree with expandable/collapsible nodes.

Not exactly what you asked, but as you know coding in JSP is frowned upon, this is rather a good way I feel.

See http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/