# How to loop self referenced class in Jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, data-structures, html-lists, self-reference

I have written a Node class for storing `tree` data structure as ,

The node looks like ,[image]

The tree i want to develop as, [image]

```
public class Node1
{
  public String data;
  public Node1 left;
  public Node1 right;   
  public static int level=0;
  public Node1(String data)
  {
     this.data=data;
     this.left=null;
     this.right=null;
  }
}
```

I store the nodes as,

```
 public void add(Node1 ht,Node1 tm,String Data)
  {
    String LNsearchData=Data.substring(0,Data.indexOf("#"));
    Data=Data.substring(Data.indexOf("#")+1);
    //System.out.println("righ"+LNsearchData);
    boolean rights=false,lefts=false;
      while(true)
      {
          if(ht.data.startsWith(LNsearchData))
          {
              System.out.println("righ"+tm.data);
              if(ht.right==null)
              {   rights=true;
                  break;
              }
               ht=ht.right;
               if(Data.length()==0)
                   break;
               LNsearchData=Data.substring(0,Data.indexOf("#"));
               Data=Data.substring(Data.indexOf("#")+1);
           }
          else
          {
              if(ht.left==null)
              {

                  break;
              }
               ht=ht.left;

               if(Data.length()==0)
                   break;
               LNsearchData=Data.substring(0,Data.indexOf("#"));
               Data=Data.substring(Data.indexOf("#")+1);
          }
      }
      if(rights==false)
      {
          System.out.println("righ"+tm.data);
          while(ht.left!=null)
          {
              ht=ht.left;
          }
          ht.left=tm;
      }
      else
      {
          while(ht.right!=null)
          {
              ht=ht.right;
          }
          ht.right=tm;
      }


}
```

Now I want to display this node object as tree structure in jsp so in jsp I did,

```
   <%
    Node1 n1=new Node1("A");
    n1.add(n1, new Node1("B"),"A#");
    n1.add(n1, new Node1("C"),"A#B#");
    n1.add(n1, new Node1("K"),"A#B#C#");
    n1.add(n1, new Node1("E"),"A#");
    n1.add(n1, new Node1("F"),"A#");
    n1.add(n1, new Node1("X"),"X#");

    n1.level=1;
    n1.traverse(n1);

%>
```

To build the tree structure in jsp,

```
<%!
public void traverse(Node1 di,JspWriter out)throws IOException
{
   //System.out.println("Par"+di.data+"level"+level);
   out.println("<li class='folder'>"+di.data);
   out.println("  <ul>");
    if(di.right!=null)
    {
      //level++;


      traverse(di.right,out);
      //level--;
    }
    if(di.left!=null)
    {
        out.print("<ul>");
        //out.print("left: "+di.data+"\n");
        traverse(di.left,out);
    }
    if(di.left==null&&di.right==null)
    {
        out.println("</ul>");
    }
   //System.out.println("returnd "+level);

}
%>
<div id="tree">
<%traverse(n1,out); %>
 </div>
```

The problem I am facing is I can able to traverse only right side of the node but I have to traverse both the side. can any one help me in solving this please.

Comment: you can try recursion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638653/displaying-tree-on-jsp-page

Comment: @syllabus Canu help me further , I have writen my recursive function  as I changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the ul tags are not well defined.
try this:

```
<%!
public void traverse(Node1 di,JspWriter out)throws IOException
{

    //System.out.println("Par"+di.data+"level"+level);
    out.println("<li class='folder'>"+di.data);
    if(di.right!=null)
    {
      out.print("<ul>");
      traverse(di.right,out);
      out.println("  </ul>");
    }
    if(di.left!=null)
    {
        traverse(di.left,out);
    }

}
%>
<div id="tree">
  <ul>
    <%traverse(n1,out); %>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: No it is not working . Sorry to not mention, I call `traverse` as ` <div id="tree">
<ul>
  <%traverse(n1,out); %>
  </ul>`</div>

Comment: give me the complete final html that you expect

Comment: This is What I want `<div id="tree">
<ul>
  <li>A
   <ul>
     <li>B
     <ul>
 <li>C
  <ul>
    <li>k
  </ul>
     </ul>
     <li>E
     <li>F
   </ul>
   <li>X
   <ul>
 <li>Y
   </ul>

</ul>
</div>
`

Comment: Thank you , its working fine. Can you please come online I have another problem on jquery.